# Find which radio button is checked from dataset in c#

Tags: c#, dataset

I'm saving the checked radio button number in the database. If the column contains the number then the radio button shows it's checked and the if the column contains null/empty then the radio button is unchecked.

```
int chk;
if(DBNull.Value.Equal(dataset.table["TableName"].Rows[i][9].ToSting()))

{ 

     chk = dsData.Tables["Option"].Rows[n][9].ToString();

     switch(chk)
     {
         case 1: radioButton1.Checked=true;
         break;
         .
         .
         .
         case 4: radioButton4.Checked=true;
         break;
     }
}

else

{
      radioButton1.Checked=false; . . .  radioButton4.Checked=false;
}
```

but it gives always empty value.
plz give the solution on it

Comment: Are you sure you're grabbing the right column? I'd retrieve it by it's name in the dataset to be sure. Also, do you have a table called "TableName"?

Answer (score 0):

Look of `empty string where you expect null` in datatable, secondly you are passing string in switch which is check but using int value you might need `case "1": instead of case 1:`

```
if(dataset.table["TableName"].Rows[i][9].ToSting() != "")
{     
     chk = dsData.Tables["Option"].Rows[n][9].ToString();    
     switch(chk)
     {
         case 1: radioButton1.Checked=true;
         break;
         .
         .
         .
         case 4: radioButton4.Checked=true;
         break;
     }
}    
else    
{
      radioButton1.Checked=false; . . .  radioButton4.Checked=false;
}
```